# Position of "alle" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-order

In a children's book, I read the following sentence:

> Die Kinder sitzen **alle** schon in ihren Bänken.

I understand the sentence as "All the children are already sitting on their benches".

The position of *alle* after the verb is something I have not seen before. I would have expected to see "Alle Kinder" or just "Die Kinder". Or does *alle* have some special meaning in this arrangement?

Comment: A very similar structure exists in ENglish. "They are all sitting ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not have a special meaning. It is used in this construct to emphasise that ALL children have taken their place already

Answer (score 2):

Let me illustrate possible locations of *alle* in another similar example:

> Die Kinder trinken ihre Limonade.

Now when putting emphasis on the fact that it was **all children**  we may say:

> 1. **Alle Kinder** trinken ihre Limonade.

or to shift the emphasis on **all were drinking**:

> 2. Die Kinder **trinken alle** ihre Limonade.

However now it becomes unclear if it were all the children, or if **all their lemonade** was drunk.

> 3. Die Kinder trinken **alle ihre Limonade**.

To clarify that the emphasis was on the lemonade we may better use *all* instead:

> 4. Die Kinder trinken **all ihre Limonade**.

---

Do not get confused by another **colloquial** use of *alle* in the meaning of *completely*:

> 5. Die Kinder trinken ihre Limonade alle.

This would mean *The children are drinking up their lemonade.*

Grammatically we could even create a tongue twister and say:

> 6. Alle Kinder trinken alle all(e) ihre Limonade alle.

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: @BarthZalewski. I only completed the existing accepted and correct answer with some examples... (an edit to the existing answer would probably have been too radical).